# PostSharp SDK breaking build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, postsharp

I just moved to Visual Studio 2015 running on Windows 10. During this process I upgraded to PostSharp 4.1.21

I'm getting the following error in some PostSharp SDK. The type in question is exactly the same type.. Anyone come across this? or know how to fix it?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Unhandled exception (4.1.21.0, postsharp.srv.4.0-x86.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.393295, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: A field name 'Doc' was found in the type 'MacroView.VSTO.Word.Precedent.Assembler`1<T>', but its type is 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document' instead of 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document'.
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.FieldDefDeclarationCollection.GetField(String name, ITypeSignature type, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.FieldRefDeclaration.GetFieldDefinition(BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.IndexGenericInstancesTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation). MacroView.DocumentAssembler.Word    C:\Repos\All MacroView Projects\MacroView.DocumentAssembler\MacroView.DocumentAssembler.Word\MacroView.DocumentAssembler.Word.csproj
```

Comment: We are aware of similar issues and we are working on a fix. The only workaround we currently know of is to fall back to VS2013. Currently it does not seem to be related to Win10.

Comment: I have a number of projects that use PostSharp. Weirdly this issue only affects one of them. So I've just removed PostSharp from that project.

Comment: The problem is related to COM interop types. When embedding interop types, C# 6 relies on Type Equivalence which PostSharp does not implement. This happens only if the current project embeds interop types and calls a method from another assembly that also have interop types embedded. This change was probably done to save some space in the metadata tables. We are working on a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in v4.1.24
(Extra sentence to make minimum length post)